# I need to make a view counter

Tags: python, html, django

I have several articles, and when viewing them, it is necessary to calculate the number of these views for each article. And show how many views on the article
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5dCh.png)
For example, I wanted to do this by clicking on the link so that it was added to "view = models.Integerfiels" 1

my models.py

```
from django.db import models
from taggit.managers import TaggableManager

class Articles(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length= 200)
    post = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to='', default="default_value")
    tags = TaggableManager()
    article_like = models.IntegerField(default='0')
    article_dislike = models.IntegerField(default='0')
    view = models.IntegerField(default='0')
    font_size = models.IntegerField()


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

views.py

```
class ArticleIndex(ListView):
    model = Articles
    template_name = 'news/posts.html'


class ArticleDetail(DetailView):
    model = Articles
    template_name = 'news/post.html'
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns=[
    path('', ArticleIndex.as_view(), name='articles_list'),
    path('<int:pk>/', ArticleDetail.as_view(), name='article_detail'),
]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What i advise you to do here is to create your own view like that

```
from django.db.models import F
def ArticleDetailView(request, pk)
      Articles.objects.filter(pk=pk).update(view=F('view') + 1)
      article_details = Articles.objects.filter(pk=pk).first()
      return render(request, 'the_path_to_your_detail_template.html', {'article_details': article_details})
```

In yout url.py you do like this :

```
path('your_url/<int:pk>/', views.ArticleDetailView, name='article_detail'),
```

In your forloop template where there all the article you just need to add the pk to the href of the anchor tag like this :

```
<a href="{{ article.pk }}">{{ article }}</a>
```

Comment: class ArticleDetail(DetailView):
    model = Articles
    template_name = 'news/post.html'
    Articles.objects.filter(pk=pk).update(view=F('view') + 1)                                                      I added a line of code to the class but now I can’t add the pk argument

Comment: I have updated the answer

Comment: I did everything but now writes The view news.views.ArticleDetail didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

Comment: Try the code that i have updated on the answer

Comment: Sorry again the error I need to add the argument pk

Comment: You havr to add the pk to your href anchor tag inside your template, the link that refer to the detailview

Comment: I made a screen and attached it to the question

Comment: i propose that you create your own view instead of using the class views, like that you will have the full control over your template, i have updated the answer with the final code

Comment: thanks!!! It's work !